# One shot-deviation property for games of imperfect information

Tags: game-theory, dynamic-programming, dynamic-games

The equivalence between subgame perfection and one-deviation property is typically stated for games of perfect information (where information sets are singletons). Does the Blackwell-style argument work for games of incomplete and/or imperfect information? (assuming continuity at infinity)

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.epicenter.name/Perea/Papers/One-deviation.pdf

Comment: Thanks! So is my understanding correct that one shot deviation-perfection equivalence holds rather broadly?

Comment: The logic has many applications, but with imperfect information it is more difficult to construct a suitable state space to make a Blackwell-type argument work. The devil tends to be in the details.